# Requirements for a Bitcoin Miner Data & Bandwidth needs

Tags: bandwidth

Can someone elaborate on the other aspects of a Bitcoin miner set up / rig's needs, things such as the amount of data in MB's per day it can get through in getting and sending, if your asymmetrical broadband connection is sufficient.

Comment: I don't see why I need to "Edit" this question Jacob, the question is fine as it is and it should be pretty darned obvious why it is different.

Answer (score 0):

Bandwith usage of a Bitcoin miner is almost negligible, in the order of 0.125 KB/sec [source](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=268679.0)

Connection stability it's more important to keep the miner working 24 hours a day.

Also, some altcoin has block generation every minute, in this case also round trip time to the mining pool is important because otherwise you have high percentage of dead share. This doesn't really apply to Bitcoins because block generation is every 10 minutes.

Comment: so based on that, were talking 320 MB a month, am I correct?